# why jquery onePageNav applying 'current' class for every 'li' item?

Tags: jquery

```
$('.navbar.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-nav').onePageNav({
        currentClass: 'active',
        changeHash: false,
        scrollSpeed: 400,
        filter: ':not(.btn)'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
problem occuring due to giving same href attribute to anchor tags.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main-nav">
            <li> <a href="#intro">intro</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#intro">services</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#intro">team</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#intro">pricing</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#intro" class="btn btn-blue">sign up</a></li>
          </ul>
</div>
```